# Getting an error( Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at or near "[" ) when I use WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(parameters)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-5, npgsql

Can I use WebSecurity.InitializeDatabase with PostgreSQL ?
I am getting an error( Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at or near "["  ) when I use WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("PGConn", "userlogin", "user", "username", true);
my
Web.config file:

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="10" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PGConn" connectionString="Server=localhost; Port=5432; Database=DBpostgre; User ID=system;Password=password;" providerName="Npgsql" />
    <add name="SQLConn" connectionString="Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=testDb;Initial Catalog=WeighingProject;Data Source=192.168.20.2\SQLEXPRESS" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.3.0" newVersion="6.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
        </providers>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
            <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
            <add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" description="Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Version= 7.24.2066.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

and my
Glabal.asax.cs code is:

```html
using DapperExtensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace PayrollContractual
{

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            InitializeAuthenticationProcess();
        }

        private void InitializeAuthenticationProcess()
        {
          if(!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("PGConn", "userlogin", "user", "username", true); // Error generates here. PGConn is the connection string name of Postgre Database,Compiler execute this statement as SQL server database string and appending "[" and "]" that's why generates error. But it works well if we connect it to the SQL server connection string that is SQLConn...

                // WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("SQLConn", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("admin", "admin123");
                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
                {
                    Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
                }
                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Manager"))
                {
                    Roles.CreateRole("Manager");
                }
                if (!Roles.RoleExists("User"))
                {
                    Roles.CreateRole("User");
                }
                            
                //    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(connectionStringName: "PGConn", userTableName: "public].[UserLogin", userIdColumn: "user_id", userNameColumn: "user_name", autoCreateTables: true);
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what change do I need to do that compiler execute this code for postgreSQL instead of SQL Server statement? Please help me out to overcome this problem. I think now I have share all the codes.
Thanks in advance.
Please refer screenshot too.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXH82.png)

Full Stack Trace:

```html
 at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|211_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__47.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteReader>d__116.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteReader>d__116.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteNonQuery>d__104.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at WebMatrix.Data.Database.Execute(String commandText, Object[] args)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.Execute(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded()
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider simpleMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean createTables, SimpleMembershipProviderCasingBehavior casingBehavior)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables, SimpleMembershipProviderCasingBehavior casingBehavior)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables, SimpleMembershipProviderCasingBehavior casingBehavior)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables)
   at PayrollContractual.MvcApplication.InitializeAuthenticationProcess() in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\PayrollContractual\PayrollContractual\Global.asax.cs:line 35
```

Comment: There's not enough information above to understand what exactly you're doing. But the `[` points to you executing SQL generated for SQL Server instead of for PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am trying to use  CreateUserAndAccount, creating role and WebSecurity.Login and logout feature. but when this code runs at startup WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("PGConn" , "userlogin", "user", "username", true); for postgreSQL its giving an error as "Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at or near "["". Please help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: So once again, you're missing a lot of details - a full stack tace, a code sample... You need to provide the necessary info for people to be able to help you. But as I wrote before, you're somehow talking to PostgreSQL but sending it SQL that was meant for SQL Server. Check where your SQL is coming from.

Comment: @Shay Rojansky thanks for reply. I have edited and share all the codes. what change do I need to do that compiler execute it (WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection) for postgreSQL instead of SQL Server statement?

Comment: As written above, please post the full exception stack trace, and describe at what point you are getting it.

Comment: Mentioned the full stack trace and also wrote comment at the line where I am getting this exception in Glabal.asax.cs code

Answer (score 0):

A default scaffolded ASP.NET Identity project contains ready-made migrations generated for SQL Server; attempting to apply them on PostgreSQL will fail. You need to remove the migration directory and regenerate the migrations for PostgreSQL.

See https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/463 for further info.

Comment: Once again, thanks for your reply. I have go through the suggested article but its not clear that how can I remove the existing migration directory (based on SQL server) and regenerate the migrations for PostgreSQL.

Comment: I suggest reading the [EF documentation on migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/) to understand how to manage migrations. Migrations are stored in a directory in your codebase (typically called "Migrations"); you can delete that and then recreate an initial migration with e.g. the EF command-line tool.